# plotly fig2plotly(gcf,'strip',false). doesnt work

Tags: matlab, surface, plotly

I am using plotly and I am trying to preserve my matlab style instead of the plotly style. A simple example is

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;
surf(Z,'FaceAlpha',0);
fig2plotly(gcf,'strip',false)
```

This should plot a surface plot with the **surfaces not colored**. Which is more like a wireframe. But what I get is the standard contour plot with the surface colored. This actually means that "'strip',false" is ignored somehow. I am using MATLAB R2014a with plotly.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: try any of the following: `surf(Z,'FaceColor','none');` or `mesh(Z,'EdgeColor','k');`

Comment: `surf` does not work, Ander.